# How do I load libgdx desktop app on mac osx?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, libgdx, lwjgl

I have been developing a simple game using libgdx on my Windows 7 PC. Recently I bought a macbook pro (mountain lion). I downloaded and installed  JRE 7 and eclipse, then cloned and imported the project. However though there are no errors in the code when I run the desktop version I the JVM loads and quickly dies. The error I get in the console is as follows:

```
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
_NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. Exit
AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

I've added JRE 7 to the build path libraries, still no joy.

The desktop launches through this code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "colourgame";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 800;
        
        new LwjglApplication(new ColourGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Really stuck on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,4711.0.html 
problem is with compatibility of JRE 7 update 6 with Lwjgl.

Problem seems to be fixed in a newer release of the library. I'm not sure if libgdx is updaetd accordingly but you can try to put the new version in your libs folder.

Comment: I updated the project with the latest libgdx nightly, no joy. I guess I'll just have to continue on my PC until it's sorted?

Comment: You can try to uninstall JRE and setup earlier version. I'm working with JRE 6 for example.

Comment: Following the conversation in that thread, I can confirm that the lwjgl **2.9.1 nightly** works fine on OSX 10.8.2 with java 1.7.0_10-ea. Great to see active support like this. Hope to see 2.9.1 released soon.

Answer (score 0):

This problem got sorted with the latest nightly build from libgdx, after doing this I got stucked into another problem, the method IntersectRectangles was missing in that release.. So i had to go back to the latest stable version and got that working, but... the problem mentioned above appeared again. So I´m going to stick to the latest stable version so I can deploy on my android device with the code working...

So temporal solution: to test while you develop use the nightly build, if you don't need the method above all should be fine(I wonder if there are more methods missing I didn´t have to use..)

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to use a stable or old release of libgdx. You might want to try to install jdk 1.6 (which I have done) in addition to jdk 1.7.

**1. Download JDK1.6**
Use this question to download jdk 1.6: [jdk 6 on mountain lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653597/jdk-6-on-mountain-lion)

**2. Add JRE home**
In eclipse, go to preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's and add jdk 1.6's home (just as your 1.7 version should be).

**3. Set run configuration to use 1.6**
Go to Run -> Run configurations -> YOUR CONFIGURATION -> JRE. Select 1.6 as the alternative JRE. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? I know this isn't the correct answer today as the 2.9.1 has long been released. But this worked as a fix for the time until the nightly 2.9.1 version was released as stable.