# Libgdx tutorial: cannot open desktop application

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to follow through the libgdx tutorial (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew), but I can't run the Desktop Application.  I read up on this, and some people said this would be caused by missing jar files.  I went back and made sure that the application was referencing the main project, and that I used the three jar files necessary: gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend lwjgl.jar, and gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar.  Still, when I try to run the application, a window pops up for a second and then crashed, and I get this error:

```
    JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
    _NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib
    JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. Exit
    AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  As a side note, some forums said that JRE 7 was causing a problem before, but it has since been fixed.  I am using JRE 1.7.0_17. I'm really stuck on this, and any help would be much appreciated.

The code looks like this:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "my-gdx-game";
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.width = 480;
    cfg.height = 320;

    new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you on a Mac, Windows or Linux?  Are you running via Eclipse or not?

Comment: [stackoverflow auto posted this] possible duplicate of [Can't load libgdx desktop app on mac osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571726/cant-load-libgdx-desktop-app-on-mac-osx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're on a Mac.  I think its still the JDK7 bug.  The problem is with the combination of LWJGL+Mac+Java.  I believe Libgdx has not upgraded to the bleeding edge of LWJGL (which may have fixed the problem?) because of other problems that the upgrade introduces (though I'm not entirely positive of this).

If you're on a Mac, then your question is probably a dup to this one:
[Can't load libgdx desktop app on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571726/cant-load-libgdx-desktop-app-on-mac-osx)

Comment: I am on a Mac actually, sorry for forgetting that part.  Thanks for the heads up.