# mac os jdk 1.8 problems vlc control JAWT not load

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

```
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load JAWT
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getWindowHandle0(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(Native.java:1879)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getComponentID(Native.java:253)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface.attach(CanvasVideoSurface.java:69)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.attachVideoSurface(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:156)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.onBeforePlay(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:315)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.play(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:705)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.playMedia(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:222)
    at viziosecure360.Travizia.AddPlayer(Travizia.java:675)
    at viziosecure360.Travizia.setDefault(Travizia.java:234)
    at viziosecure360.Travizia$1.run(Travizia.java:187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question & share codes ?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: This looks related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571726/cant-load-libgdx-desktop-app-on-mac-osx which implies that the lwgl library that is being used in jvlc isn't compatible with java 7 (or newer) on OSX.

Answer (score 6):

vlcj/LibVLC requires a heavyweight AWT component to render its video.

There is no longer any AWT in JDK 1.7 and later on OSX. The UI toolkit on OSX is now fully lightweight.

So the optimal way of using vlcj on OSX no longer works.

What you have to do is use the so-called ["direct" media player [1]](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.0.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/direct/DirectMediaPlayer.html) rather than the "embedded" one.

The downside to using the direct media player is that you have to render the video yourself somehow, using a BufferedImage, a hardware accelerated volatile image, a PixelWriter or something else.

This approach typically uses more memory and more CPU, and is a bit more inconvenient.

On the plus side, it is possible to achieve smooth HD video playback using this method.

Also on the plus side, you can process the video buffer in some way if you want, and easily overlay lightweight widgets/labels on top of the video using this approach.

There is an example provided in the vlcj test sources that shows one way how to do this (there is too much code to reproduce here so I'll provide [a stable link [2]](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.0.1/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/direct/DirectTestPlayer.java)).

There is also a long discussion in the [project issue tracker [3]](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/205) on this subject.

[1] http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.0.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/direct/DirectMediaPlayer.html

[2] https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.0.1/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/direct/DirectTestPlayer.java

[3] https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/205

Amazingly there's a potential, though clearly sub-optimal, solution which is to use a Windows 1.7/1.8 JVM on OSX using Wine. I have not tried it but I have been told it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am few years late with my answer but it may help. You should use CallbackMediaPlayerComponent instead of EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent. [Source link](https://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/direct-rendering) has the working code you can copy/paste and view MP4 with video and sound on OSX, Java 19, VLCJ 4.8.1.