# Compatibility issues when I test VLCJ player from Windows to OSX

Tags: java, media-player, vlc, vlcj

I'm trying to use VLCJ to create a simple Java player.
Following Github's examples, I made a simple player which works well on Windows; when I tested it on last OSX release, it didn't seem to work and if you press play on a video it crashes returning me the following error:

```
15:27:10.130 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer - play() 
15:27:10.130 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer - onBeforePlay() 
15:27:10.130 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer - attachVideoSurface() 
15:27:10.130 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.v.CanvasVideoSurface - attach() 
_NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. 
Exit MacBook
```

Here's how I made the player:

```
v = new Canvas();
mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(fullScreenStrategy);
mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(v));
frame.add(v);
```

Anybody has a clue?

VLCJ version: 3.4
JAVA version: 1.8

Comment: This is a well-known problem: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/205, and probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638820/mac-os-jdk-1-8-problems-vlc-control-jawt-not-load

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see it, this helps me a lot thank you.